# Scope Issue With `this` Inside React Component Lifecycle Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance, scope, react-router

I have a React class component defined like so:

### JS

```
import { Component } from 'react';

export class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    MyOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    let map = MyOverlay();
    function MyOverlay() {
      // constructor
      ...
    }

    MyOverlay.prototype.onAdd = () => {

      // I need this from OverlayView
      let panes = this.getPanes(); 

      // Another place where I need `this`
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      this.div_ = div;

      // Attach an Event Handler to the Overlay
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, 'click', () => {

          // I need access to the props belonging to the Search Component, 
          //   but, now, using `.bind(this)` is out of the question because the 
          //   outer function needs access to OverlayView's `this`
          this.props.history.push(); // `this` is now out of scope.
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see from the comments, I have a constructor inside a lifecycle hook that is creating a new instance of OverlayView. Because of that, I'm taken out of the scope of the Search Component when I'm writing inside the methods and event handlers of MapOverlay.

### My Question

How can I call the props of Search from inside the `click` event handler (which is inside the OverlayView's `onAdd()` method?

Do I need to create another component called MapOverlay and then pass history into that? I'm just confused as to how I'm going to get the scope of `this` into that event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store the 'this' of the component first at a variable. You can access it inside componentDidMount() outside the MyOverlay scope. Afterwards, you can use it whenever you want.

```
import { Component } from 'react';

export class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    MyOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    let map = MyOverlay();
    function MyOverlay() {
      // constructor
      ...
    }

    // ===== store it first here ====
    let history = this.props.history;
    // ==============================

    MyOverlay.prototype.onAdd = () => {
      let panes = this.getPanes(); 
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      this.div_ = div;
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, 'click', () => {

          // ===== history of the Search component =====
          history.push();
          // ==============================
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I'll get back to you as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: I feel like this is such a simple solution to a problem that I thought was going to be much larger. :D